# AVAudioPlayer gives nill for the path Swift 3 xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

I got a problem with my audio player. When I launch my viewcontroller it gives nill on the url's and I have no idea how this is possible.. I tried to debug and look for the problem but I have no clue whats going on.

Here is the code:

```
// VARS AUDIO
    var sfxFive: AVAudioPlayer!
    var sfxFour: AVAudioPlayer!
    var sfxThree: AVAudioPlayer!
    var sfxtwo: AVAudioPlayer!
    var sfxOne: AVAudioPlayer!
    var sfxGo: AVAudioPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {

            let resourcePathFive = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "five", ofType: "m4a")!
            let urlFive = URL(fileURLWithPath: resourcePathFive)
            try sfxFive = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlFive)

            let resourcePathFour = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "four", ofType: "m4a")!
            let urlFour = URL(fileURLWithPath: resourcePathFour)
            try sfxFour = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlFour)

            let resourcePathThree = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "three", ofType: "m4a")!
            let urlThree = URL(fileURLWithPath: resourcePathThree)
            try sfxThree = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlThree)

            let resourcePathTwo = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "two", ofType: "m4a")!
            let urlTwo = URL(fileURLWithPath: resourcePathTwo)
            try sfxtwo = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlTwo)

            let resourcePathOne = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "one", ofType: "m4a")!
            let urlOne = URL(fileURLWithPath: resourcePathOne)
            try sfxOne = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlOne)

            let resourcePathGo = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "go", ofType: "m4a")!
            let urlGo = URL(fileURLWithPath: resourcePathGo)
            try sfxGo = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlGo )

            sfxFive.prepareToPlay()
            sfxFour.prepareToPlay()
            sfxThree.prepareToPlay()
            sfxtwo.prepareToPlay()
            sfxOne.prepareToPlay()
            sfxGo.prepareToPlay()

        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
}


func timerRunning() {

        if timeElapsed == 5 {
            sfxFive.play()
        }else if timeElapsed == 4 {
            sfxFour.play()
        }else if timeElapsed == 3 {
            sfxThree.play()
        }else if timeElapsed == 2 {
            sfxtwo.play()
        }else if timeElapsed == 1 {
            sfxOne.play()
        }else if timeElapsed == 0 {
            sfxGo.play()
        }
}
```

The audio files are located in the root directory.

Does anybody see the problem?

Kind Regards,
Kevin.

Comment: Check your Target's Build Phases, if your m4a file is not listed under Copy Bundle Resources phase group, add it, then Clean, and Run again.

Comment: Under that map there is no m4a file

Comment: Add them in that group. Clean your project and Run again.

Comment: @Wolverine will give it a shot now

Comment: Check your URL now, if they are giving proper URL then may be you need to check the code written for play. Debug is using breakpoint to get more clear idea.

Comment: The you need to check the code for your Timer I think, I think the function "timerRunning" is responsible for playing the files, so you should check that.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer. please mark it as answer if it has solve your problem so it will be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `yourProject -> Target's Build`, In that **under Copy Bundle Resources phase group,**, if your m4a file is not listed, then Add them in that group.

Clean your project and Run again.